# UItableViewCell updating wrong cell label text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, geocoding

I have a UITableView, Where I'm loading address from Geocoder by latlng.
when I scroll down tableview first time all is fine & working in good manner.
But Problem is when I'm scroll up then all address lost their cell. I mean
the address of 5th cell now showing on 1st cell.

**This is my cellForRowAt tableview method**

```
        let cell  = self.mytableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCell
        let position = indexPath.row
        let data         =  mVehicleList[position]
        getAddress(lat: data.latitude.toD(), lng: data.longitude.toD(), text: cell.lbAddress)
        // getAddress is extenstion of ViewCOnroller which is give addres of latlng
```

**This my getAddress(lat,lng,label) extension**

```
extension UIViewController {

    func getAddress(lat:Double,lng :Double, text : UILabel)
    {

        let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if(placemarks != nil){
                if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                    let pm = placemarks![0]

                    if(pm.subLocality != nil && pm.subAdministrativeArea != nil)
                    {
                        text.text = pm.subLocality!+" "+pm.subAdministrativeArea!

                    }else{
                        guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {

                            return
                        }


                        if let formattedAddress = addressDict["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [String] {

                            text.text = formattedAddress.joined(separator: ", ")

                        }
                    }


                }else{
                    text.text = "No address found"
                }
            }
})   } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of dequeuing

```
if let addr = data.addressText {
   cell.lbAddress.text = addr
}
else {
  getAddress(indexPath.row,lat: data.latitude.toD(), lng: data.longitude.toD(), text: cell.lbAddress)
 }
```

I suggest to geocode the location and alter the model with the retrieved address , then reload the table/indexPath , and that will save you from getting the same address again and again when you scroll the table , just check the model's location if nil then start the geocode , if not then assign it to the label

```
func getAddress(_ index:Int,lat:Double,lng :Double, text : UILabel) {
    ///
     mVehicleList[index].addressText = formattedAddress.joined(separator: ", ")
     // reload table/index
 }


class model {

 var state:State = .none

  func geocode(){

    gurad state == .none else { return }

    state = .geocoding

     CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation//// {

          state = .geocoded // if success
     }
  }
}
enum State {
 case geocoding,gecoded,none
}
```

Comment: @RobertDresler   table cells are reused so before the new address is retrieved , the labels has the text from the old one

Comment: this solution working but this is eating my GEO CODING Hits. is there any solution if I hit GEO Coding only one time per cell

Comment: the geocode occurs for visible cells , and by this it'll occur only once in best case for every item

Comment: your solution is really good and helpful. But I'm novice in IOS. please can you simplify your code. thanks @Sh_Khan