# Load One Element Asynchronously in TableViewCell after Other Element Loaded in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I would like to load a tableview with a combination of synchronous and asynchronous (remote) data. The synchronous data loads immediately.  How can I get the asynchronous data to load when it is ready?  Do I put something in cellforRow or in viewwill appear?

Right now I set the label value in the tableview cell but the data is not updating

Here is my cellforRow code:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        let row = indexPath.row
        cell.textLabel?.text = Places[row].name
                Utilities.shared.getWeather(query: Places[row].name as NSString) { (response1) in
                    print(response1)
                   DispatchQueue.main.async  {
                    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = response1
                    }          
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current behavior loads the data every scroll , and in worst case loads the same data many times at the same instant , so you need to keep it once by putting that logic inside your model to grab the required content and update it's content with it , then reload the table / indexPath an example is described [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867835/5820010)